# Scheduled Jobs with Custom Clock Processes in Python with APScheduler is not running

Tags: python, python-3.x, heroku, scrapy, heroku-cli

I push my scrapy project on heroku. I need to automate some task. So from documentation I come to know about the custom clock with Apsheduler.
This is my directory structure:

```
.
├── bin
│   └── testargs.py
├── clock.py
├── Dockerfile
├── :hrsZp[do
├── newsfetch
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── items.py
│   ├── middlewares.py
│   ├── pipelines.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-34.pyc
│   │   ├── middlewares.cpython-34.pyc
│   │   ├── pipelines.cpython-34.pyc
│   │   └── settings.cpython-34.pyc
│   ├── settings.py
│   └── spiders
│       ├── indiatv.py
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── ndtv.py
│       ├── __pycache__
│       │   ├── indiatv.cpython-34.pyc
│       │   ├── __init__.cpython-34.pyc
│       │   ├── ndtv.cpython-34.pyc
│       │   ├── republic.cpython-34.pyc
│       │   ├── thehindu.cpython-34.pyc
│       │   └── zee.cpython-34.pyc
│       ├── republic.py
│       ├── thehindu.py
│       └── zee.py
├── p1.py
├── Procfile
├── requirements.txt
├── scrapy.cfg
└── setup.py

5 directories, 30 files
```

This is my requirement file

```
Scrapy>=1.0.2
cffi>=1.12.2
psycopg2
APScheduler==3.0.0
```

And here is my clock.py file

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler

sched = BlockingScheduler()

@sched.scheduled_job('interval', minutes=3)
def timed_job():
    print('This job is run every three minutes.')

sched.start()
```

I am not getting any message(**This job is run every three minutes**) to print in my heroku log. I have commit all the changes and deploy the application. Kindly help to run my script so I move further to automate the task.

This is the current state of log:

```
2019-03-14T14:27:40.979762+00:00 heroku[clock.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-03-14T14:27:47.752630+00:00 heroku[clock.1]: Starting process with command `: python clock.py`
2019-03-14T14:27:48.437785+00:00 heroku[clock.1]: State changed from starting to up
2019-03-14T14:27:50.480830+00:00 heroku[clock.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2019-03-14T14:27:50.466390+00:00 heroku[clock.1]: Process exited with status 0
```

Answer (score 0):

> `2019-03-14T14:27:47.752630+00:00 heroku[clock.1]: Starting process with command ': python clock.py'`

This looks like there is a typo in your Procfile, as the command should read `'python clock.py'` (note the missing colon). The proper line for your Procfile is:
`clock: python clock.py`

Also, scale up the clock process if you haven't done so already. In the Heroku CLI use the command `heroku ps:scale clock=1`.

See the [Heroku page for APScheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/clock-processes-python#clock-process-type) for more details.